# ¿Existe una forma posible de usar el case del switch como "case (rango de números)"?

Tags: c++

La forma en que lo digité en el título es obviamente errónea, pero es para que entiendan a lo que me refiero. Normalmente un ***switch*** case 1, el *case* siempre obedece a un entero, pero qué pasa si quiero un case que lea un rango de enteros posibles dentro de la variable del switch, por ejemplo

```
switch(edad())
     case (edad()>=1)
```

Aquí un ejemplo en código fácil de lo que me refiero.

```
switch(edadGato())
    {
    case 1:
        cout<<"Al gato le corresponde la vacuna de la Rabia";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"Al gato le corresponde la vacuna de la Panleucopenia";
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"Basado en la edad, al gato no le corresponde ninguna edad";
        break;
    }
```

Si la edad fuese 2, no me detectaría que ya tendría una vacuna pendiente por tener más de un año (case 1), por eso, mi duda sobre si existe una forma algo como case (rango de números).

Nota: Sé que con if es más fácil, pero si en switch es posible, compártanlo conmigo. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** es posible ... con un pequeño matiz: el `break` es **opcional**:

```
switch( edadGato( ) ) {
case 3:
  cout << "Al gato le corresponde la vacuna de la Panleucopenia.\n";

case 2:
  cout << "Al gato le falta una, que no se cual es.\n";

case 1:
  cout << "Al gato le corresponde la vacuna de la Rabia.\n";
  break;

default:
  cout << "Basado en la edad, al gato no le corresponde ninguna vacuna.\n";
  break;
}
```

Aunque hay otras formas, mas aptas en el caso de que sean muchos los valores ... solo hay que dejar volar la imaginación :-)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

const std::unordered_map< int, std::vector< std::string > > VacunasPorEdad{
  { 1, { "Rabia" } },
  { 2 , { "Desconocido" } },
  { 3, { "Panleucopenia", "Desconocido2" } }
};
constexpr int EDAD_MAXIMA = 3;

std::vector< const std::string * > generarListaVacunas( int edad ) {
  std::vector< const std::string * > result;

  for( int idx = 1; ( idx <= edad ) && ( idx <= EDAD_MAXIMA ); ++idx ) {
    const auto mapIter = VacunasPorEdad.find( idx );

    if( mapIter != VacunasPorEdad.cend( ) ) {
      for( const auto &iter : mapIter->second ) {
        result.push_back( &iter );
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

int main( ) {
  int edad;

  std::cout << "Edad del gato: ";
  std::cin >> edad;

  auto lista = generarListaVacunas( edad );

  std::cout << "\nLista de vacunas pendiente:\n";
  for( auto ptr : lista ) {
    std::cout << " * " << *ptr << ".\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```